# Как обратиться к методу класса php?

Tags: php

У меня большой объект `$obj`, обращаюсь к нужным элементам `$obj->dish->content` без проблем, но затем упираюсь вот во что:

Функция `print_r($obj->dish->content)` мне выводит вот такую конструкцию:

```
(
  [1300] => stdClass Object
      (
          [foo] => 1 порц
          [kbju] => 440 / 29 / 16 / 45
      )

  [1400] => stdClass Object
      (
          [bar] => 1 порц
          [kbju] => 440 / 29 / 16 / 45
      )
)
```

как мне обращаться к объектам внутри? Через $obj->dish->content->1300 - ругается. А как еще мне дотянуться до `[bar]` и `[kbju]` ?

PS Этот объект создается из JSON

Comment: `$obj->dish->content[1300]` и `$obj->dish->content[1300]->foo`

Comment: неа, ошибка PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$obj->dish->content->{1300}->foo`

Comment: Спасибо!) Это работает!))